# How to parse the file with international words in python

Tags: python, regex

I have files with the words written on different speaking languages. I would like to parse them using python programming language to have the same structure in all files.
Currently files contain the lines like

```
1. word1
24. word2
- word3
word4
** word5
```

The goal is to have all of them written like

```
** word
```

I have already some code reading from one file, fr, and writing to new one, fw, like this

```
    for line in fr:
        match = re.search(r'^\*\* .*', line)
        if match:
        fw.write(line)
```

I have two questions.

First question. How to write regexp, so it will be searching for line starting not from alpha character and remove everything that is before alpha character?

I have tried like this

```
fw.write(re.sub(r'(^([^a-zA-Z].*)([a-zA-Z])*.*)', "** \1", line))
```

but it doesn't work.

Second question. How to verify if the string starts with alpha character. I have tried

```
print line[0].isalpha()
```

it returns ?. Do I need to have it unicode first?

Thank you.

Comment: Two questions: which languages do you deal with? how is the file encoded?

Comment: @thg435, it's mentioned in title and in tags, it's python language. How I can find out the encoding type? It looks like it's ascii.

Comment: You said "words in __different languages__" - which are these? Does the file contain something like ö or ß or æ?

Comment: @thg435, one of them for sure is Russian language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try matching any of the possible line prefixes, then collect the rest of the line as your word of interest.

```
pat = re.compile(r'^(\d+\. |- |\*\* )?(?P<word>.*)')
```

The first group defines the possible prefixes (you might want to fix it up for one or more spaces instead of a literal space). The second, named, group gets the word.

Comment: @Pirce, would you please comment this. Why 1 is specified? You meant digit, i.e \d*?
What ? means? Extension?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say \d+, not digit.  1 is specified because I made a mistake.  The ? after the first parenthetical grouping means zero or one (to handle the case where there's a word, but no prefix.  The ?P<word> is how you give a string tag to identify the stuff you are matching in that (in our case, the second) group.

Answer (score 2):

The unicode property for a letter is: `\pL`. Put this in place of `[a-zA-Z]`

use it as:

```
^\PL*(\pL+)
```

That means 0 or more non letter followed by 1 or more letters captured in group 1.

Comment: I have changed line onto <code>fw.write(re.sub(r'(^([^\pL]*.*)([\pL])*.*)', "** \1", line))</code> but I see like <code>** ^A</code> in result file.

Comment: @yart:Do you want the string to begin with a letter or a non-letter?

Comment: result string should like
** word
it means two starts and then space and then word containing only alpha characters. It also means no numbers or - or _.

Comment: the write line should be like this
fw.write(re.sub(r'^\PL*(\pL+).*', "** \1", line)) ?

Comment: Python’s `re` module doesn’t grok Unicode properties. You have to use Matthew Barnett’s replacement `regex` library instead if you want decent Unicode support in Python.

Comment: @tchrist, does it mean that using standard Python libraries won't help  solving the issue with the content written on different languages?

Comment: @yart For the most part, yes, that does mean that. The standard Python `re` library **does not meet the minimal level of conformance** specified by [UTS#18 Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/). Matthew Barnett’s `regex` library, is contrast, does meet all Level 1 requirements and a few from level 2, like grapheme support via `\X`. The standard `re` library doesn’t even do Unicode casefolding, which means that it won’t correctly match `tschüß` and `TSCHÜSS`, or `Σίσυφος` and `ΣΊΣΥΦΟΣ`. The `regex` library, however, does manage al that and much more correctly.

Comment: @yart Matthew’s `regex` library has many other useful things as well, and works for both Python2 and Python3. It gives (nearly) complete access to the myriad Unicode properties, not just the minimal set from UTS#18’s RL1.2 and RL1.2a, but all the rest of them, too. Without **full properties** and **grapheme support**, you really can’t deal with Unicode in regexes. Just use Matthew’s library. It’s very cool in other ways, too. It is also likely to become the standard Python library for these things, included as part of the standard release, in the reasonably near future.

Answer (score 0):

Import the `codecs` module and open the file with

```
fp = codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

If your file has a mix of languages, this is the most likely to be right. If not, figure out which encoding you should be using. This will give you unicode and your REs will have a hope of working correctly.

Comment: this is what I got on attempt to start updated code.
fw.write(line)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0432' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You need to use codecs.open (with the utf-8 encoding) for writing, too.

Comment: I have specified
    fr = codecs.open (filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    fw = codecs.open (os.path.basename(filename) + "_udpated", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
When I open result file I see a lot of
** ^A
records.